# No content is added to ask the textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea, append

I have a textarea:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("textarea").append("Hola");
}
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="txt"></textarea>
```

what I want is that when you load the page adding the word "Hello" to textarea but not because it does not work ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 problems :

- you're missing a closing parenthesis (the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) should show it)
- you must use [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to change the value of an input.
- you use jQuery before you import it

Use

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("textarea").val("Hola");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Val? I know that function ... you mean value? But it is not an input textarea ...

Comment: See edit : I linked to the function and it mentions textarea.

Comment: Thansk Dom for the link. I was going to link to [Using Chrome's console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) but your link is good too.